# React hook , ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In video.js's official document https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html

we have

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    // instantiate Video.js
    this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
    });
  }
```

I want to create functional component with hooks

```js
export default function VideoPlayer(props) {
  const player = useRef(null);
  const videoNode = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    player.current = videojs(videoNode.current, props);

    return () => {
      if (player.current) {
        player.current.dispose()
      }
    }
  }, []);//I have problem with dependency array
  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={videoNode} className="video-js"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have warning

> ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

If I change dependency array from `[]` to `[props]` `useEffect` runs on each render , I just want run it on first time , like `componentDidMount`

How can I exactly create `componentDidMount` using hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects), you used `useEffect` as intended. An empty dependency array means that it will run only once (as `componentDidMount`). The error pointed out informs you if you actually had other intentions, the effect won't render again.

To dismiss the error, you can simply paste the following comment
`// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` at the end of `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  player.current = videojs(videoNode.current, props);

  return () => {
    if (player.current) {
      player.current.dispose()
    }
  }
}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

**REFERENCE**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854902/11023871) explains it more thoroughly